# Visual Studio 2012 window border leaks onto other screen

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio

I have several 30" monitors and as a result, I use the Win+Left/Right to tile windows to the left and right side of each screen. I've noticed an annoying feature of Visual Studio 2012 is that it seems to "leak" onto the next screen. I can see a line on the adjacent screen as if the edge of the window is slightly over the border. Anyone else see this? Is it a bug?

This is on Windows 7 64 bit. I've never seen this with any other application.

Comment: Leaks for me if I use those key combos.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this could be considered a "bug"; rather a side effect of the way Visual Studio 2012 draws the glowing window borders. Each of the top, left, right, and bottom border are actually separate windows, with the class name "VisualStudioGlowWindow"; you can use Spy++ to verify this.

According to Spy++, the four drop shadow windows are hidden when the main window is maximized. Because Aero-docking the main window to one of the edges of the screen isn't a fully "maximized" window state, the code that manages the shadow windows doesn't hide them and they end up "leaking" into the adjacent monitor.

It would be interesting to see if this issue remains on Windows 10, as the glowing border feature is built-in to the operating system in that version and should manage itself accordingly when a window is maximized. Unfortunately, I do not have a multi-monitor setup on Windows 10 to test this.

Answer (score 0):

This has been bothering me as well, so I made a small utility based on Michael pointing out the distinct class name. The default config should autohide all new Visual Studio glows every 5 seconds. Let me know if you hit any snags!

https://github.com/9001/windowhider/releases